# Light distro for intel atom

Tags: intel

Looking for a light distro for my small intel atom laptop.
Uses:-
i happily use ranger,mplayer,luakit,zathura and awesome...don't suggest to use lubunt as it is my last option.
Cannot use or install anything which has no option to connect with 3g dongle out of the box so arch and gentoo are out of my hands.
Must be compitable to install awesomewm.my laptop ran xubuntu well,just for information,but i want light,stable and fast.salix seemed to me a good option but it doesnot support awesomewm but ratpoison,can do for me but i wasn't sure it has dongle support out of the box..so please suggest the os of my needs.. Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Crunchbag http://crunchbang.org/, it is Debian based, so you should be able to install all the packages you need (Ubuntu is also Debian based).

Answer (score 1):

Linux Lite is a good choice, or at the very least worth trying. It is based on Ubuntu and the hardware requirements are low. I use it on my N130 netbook with an Atom processor and it runs pretty fast.

[**Linux Lite OS**](https://www.linuxliteos.com/index.html)

[image]

Comment: Can confirm. I installed on an Acer Aspire One (1.66 GHz with 1MB RAM Intel Atom) and it is the fastest (and nicest) distro I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_netbook-oriented_Linux_distributions) helps. MaxPup, LXPup or AntiX are also lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

My own preference for a lightweight distro is antiX (current version is 13.2, 14 is in beta).  It has a choice of several lightweight GUI desktops (IceWM, Fluxbox, JWM, and WMII) and you can install others (if you have the resources, you can even use KDE), fits on a CD (not a DVD), installs as easily as Ubuntu, and I currently run it on a 300 MHz, 288 MiB RAM Pentium II laptop with 16 GB Compact Flash replacing the original HD (shared with Windows 98, which uses 3 GB) -- it runs pretty well in as little as 128 MiB RAM.

anitX is based on Debian (as is Ubuntu), and during install gives the choice to use Stable, Testing, or Unstable repositories; Stable is (currently, early 2015) the same base as Ubuntu 14, while Testing is the generation that will become the next Stable (Ubuntu 15) after Canonical makes their own changes to the Debian core.  Unstable is a little riskier, in terms of new updates possibly being broken and breaking your system, but more cutting edge in terms of new developments.  My own antiX installations are both on Testing: they get a hundred or so updates a week, but I'll never have to reinstall or upgrade, so long as Debian continues development with its current process.

If your system doesn't have UEFI, installing antiX is as simple as burning the ISO to a CD or installing it on a USB stick or other flash drive, and booting from the media; once the Live session is running, there's a menu option to install antiX, and installing works very much like any other Linux installer (at least from the Debian clan).

Re: your 3G dongle, I have no experience with that sort of hardware, but antiX happily connects via wifi on a PCMCIA card using wicd, I don't anticipate any issues with the dongle (you might ask on the [antiX forum](http://antix.freeforums.org/index.php) with hardware details to be sure).